# Django/Python How can I Localize Quotes for Rendered Text?

Tags: python, django, localization, quotes

I generate a text like this:

```
Are you sure to delete "{{ object.name }}"?
```

The name of the object is sometimes set into quotes, sometimes not.

I am aware, I could just create a localized string with quotes like `"„%s“"` add a comment, and let it get translated for each language. This would be my **plan B**, because choosing the correct quotes is more a topic of typography as of translation and often done wrong.

Therefore if it is somehow possible to resolve the correct quotes for the current locale would make this simpler and safer.

Therefore my question:

**Is there a way/function to automatically generate correct quotes for the currently selected locale?**

Comment: Don't the HTML entities `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` use the correct formatting automatically?

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't know, do they? How will the browser know the locale to choose?

Comment: the locale set in the browser, which is usually also the locale django uses to select the language.

Comment: i'm not sure myself, that's why I suggested to try. Otherwise, the only solution I see is via the translation files (maybe write a script that fixes the quotation marks in .po files)